# Can I use these @media specifications?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media

I'm trying to construct my first responsive website. I'm wondering whether I can use the following code:

In the head of html:

```
< meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

In a single CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px) {}
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 480px) and (max-device-width : 960px) {}
```

This would be for 3 types of devices. Everything with a greater resolution than 960px has a third specification, not specified by `@media`. I cut down:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 960px)  {}
```

Is this OK?

Can I also simplify the code by using only:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px) {}
```

Because I think that the tablet and PC versions are going to be pretty similar. So the question is, do I need 3 @media or can I only use 1 @media & everything that is not specified by @media is for a PC or a Tablet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Every stylesheet rule which is **not nested** in media-queries is used on **all devices**.

You can use `@media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px) {}` and nest all rules in there which should apply for devices with max-device-width: 480px.

There are two possible ways to create responsive sites with CSS: **mobile-first** and **desktop-first**. If you're using your general stylesheets for desktop devices and media-queries for smaller devices it is a **desktop-first** attempt.

Just to go in more detail, I'm using these stylesheets for my projects, which I found online ( I'm not quite sure where I found it, so if somebody knows I'll add credits ). These seem to be the most accurate media-queries:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    /* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you actually use all of the media-queries on every website? Isn't it sufficient to use 1-3?

Comment: @Baki No, I don't. I often try to avoid them, by using smart CSS rules. Setting the content to `width: 100%`, with `max-width: 1000px` for example. But for some cases it is usefull to cover all devices and optimize your site. If you can handle to use less queries do that! I guess your solution will work quite well, but you need to check the results.

Answer (score 0):

@media only screen and (max-
device-width : 480px) {}
@media only screen and (min-
device-width : 481px) and (max-
device-width : 960px) {}

The min-device-width should have a pixel more than the max-device-width as corrected above. Elseb when the screen width is 480px, it will conflict and the second first condition will be overridden by the second condition. This means it will render a pc design for 480px screen resolution which is a mobile device.
Hope it helps.